# Laminas / Zend framework 3 form annotations

Tags: php, zend-framework, annotations, frameworks, laminas

I was working on Laminas or Zend framework 3 and I tried to use annotation to geneate form

[Using Annotations](https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-form/quick-start/#using-annotations)

But  get this message

```
Message:
Class 'Laminas\Code\Annotation\AnnotationManager' not found
```

My Controller :

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Application\Controller;

use Laminas\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Laminas\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Laminas\Form\Annotation\AnnotationBuilder;
 
use Application\Entity\User;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
      

         $builder = new AnnotationBuilder();
         $form    = $builder->createForm(User::class);
         
        return new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

My Entity :

```
 <?php 
namespace Application\Entity;
use Laminas\Form\Annotation;


/**
 * @Annotation\Name("user")
 * @Annotation\Hydrator("Laminas\Hydrator\ObjectProperty")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @Annotation\Exclude()
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @Annotation\Filter({"name":"StringTrim"})
     * @Annotation\Validator({"name":"StringLength", "options":{"min":1, "max":25}})
     * @Annotation\Validator({"name":"Regex","options":{"pattern":"/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]{0,24}$/"}})
     * @Annotation\Attributes({"type":"text"})
     * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Username:"})
     */
    public $username;

    /**
     * @Annotation\Type("Laminas\Form\Element\Email")
     * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Your email address:"})
     */
    public $email;
}
```

This is the error I get :

```
An error occurred
An error occurred during execution; please try again later.
Additional information:
Error
File:
C:\dev\htdocs\laminas-mvc-skeleton\vendor\laminas\laminas-form\src\Annotation\AnnotationBuilder.php:178
Message:
Class 'Laminas\Code\Annotation\AnnotationManager' not found
Stack trace:
#0 C:\dev\htdocs\laminas-mvc-skeleton\vendor\laminas\laminas-form\src\Annotation\AnnotationBuilder.php(221): Laminas\Form\Annotation\AnnotationBuilder->getAnnotationManager()
#1 C:\dev\htdocs\laminas-mvc-skeleton\vendor\laminas\laminas-form\src\Annotation\AnnotationBuilder.php(257): Laminas\Form\Annotation\AnnotationBuilder->getFormSpecification('Application\\Ent...')
#2 C:\dev\htdocs\laminas-mvc-skeleton\module\Application\src\Controller\IndexController.php(21): Laminas\Form\Annotation\AnnotationBuilder->createForm('Application\\Ent...')
#3 C:\dev\htdocs\laminas-mvc-skeleton\vendor\laminas\laminas-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(77): Application\Controller\IndexController->indexAction()
#4 C:\dev\htdocs\laminas-mvc-skeleton\vendor\laminas\laminas-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(331): Laminas\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#5 C:\dev\htdocs\laminas-mvc-skeleton\vendor\laminas\laminas-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(188): Laminas\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#6 C:\dev\htdocs\laminas-mvc-skeleton\vendor\laminas\laminas-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractController.php(103): Laminas\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#7 C:\dev\htdocs\laminas-mvc-skeleton\vendor\laminas\laminas-mvc\src\DispatchListener.php(139): Laminas\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Laminas\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Laminas\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#8 C:\dev\htdocs\laminas-mvc-skeleton\vendor\laminas\laminas-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(331): Laminas\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#9 C:\dev\htdocs\laminas-mvc-skeleton\vendor\laminas\laminas-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(188): Laminas\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#10 C:\dev\htdocs\laminas-mvc-skeleton\vendor\laminas\laminas-mvc\src\Application.php(331): Laminas\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Laminas\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#11 C:\dev\htdocs\laminas-mvc-skeleton\public\index.php(42): Laminas\Mvc\Application->run()
#12 {main}
```

Thank you for your support .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you check the existence of AnnotationManager in your vendor?
It should be under vendor/laminas/laminas-code/src/Annotation/AnnotationManager.php

Like you can see, it's located in a seperate package called laminas/laminas-code.
Depending on your composer require statements it is not loaded by default.

Do you have any output with `composer why laminas/laminas-code`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :) ... That was the problem !
I add this and it work 

composer require laminas/laminas-code
composer require laminas/laminas-form
composer require laminas/laminas-i18n